# Execute multiple Scalatests in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have multiple IntelliJ (Scala) modules that have build.sbt file and scalatest code.

I also created ScalaTest configurations for each of them.

[image]

I can run the test one by one, but is it possible to run all of them at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess for executing multiple tests, one may need to use `sbt aggregation` as is explained in [Execute multiple Scalatests in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972266/execute-multiple-scalatests-in-sbt).

In IntelliJ IDE, we can just use the ScalaTest for testing and debugging a test for one module.

Using batch mode, one can easily execute the multiple tests with sbt.

[Adding module dependency information in sbt's build.sbt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275059/adding-module-dependency-information-in-sbts-build-sbt-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can run all the scalatest of one module:

- right click on the (sub)module
- run >
- ScalaTests in [module name]

But I don't know [How to run all scalatest of a multi-modules sbt with intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35523333/1206998) :-\

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a maven project, you can try using the 'test' command (in screenshot) to run all tests. This will execute all the tests under your test/scala dir.

[image]