# How to run all scalatest of a multi-modules sbt with intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I can run:

1. a specific scala test

   - either by right clicking on the test and choose `run`
   - or if I have run it once previously, by selecting the test in run menu > `run...`
2. I can run all junit tests by making a new `run/debug configuration` > + > junit > `test kind = all in package` > `search for tests = in whole project`
3. I can run all scalatest (or junit) of one sub-project: right click on the project > run > scalatest in [module name]

But if I do the same as (2) with a scala test (+ > scala test > test kind...) the first test fails very strangely (it seems an `object` is not instantiated) while the same test pass if I run it using (1) or (3)

Config:

- sbt with multiple subproject
- intellij CE 15.0.2
- scala plugin 2.1.0
- scala 2.10

Bonus question: how to run all tests (junit and scalatest)?

Comment: That's a very good question, I don't know why it was down-voted. Obviously, you can run `sbt test` in a terminal, but I would be interested as well to know if I can have the IntelliJ IDEA GUI run all tests at once.

Comment: Why the down vote? Don't be shy, explain yourself

Comment: I can do `sbt test`, which is done at least by the continuous integration system. But running them in intellij has several advantages. Mainly, it can run in debug, it has a nicer display (and display time taken by each test) and it has more chance to be run by my non-IT colleagues who are not comfortable with sbt.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to right click on the root directory of the project and click `Run "All Tests"`. This recursively searches for tests in your project, and will run the tests in each module.